# what exactly is .bash_profile.pysave?

Tags: python, bash

I just noticed that I have a .bash_profile and a .bash_profile.pysave and I was wondering what the .pysave was, if I can delete it and how/why it came into existence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When python is installed, some installers will modify your `.bash_profile`. They save your previous version in `.bash_profile.pysave`.

Comment: awesome. Thank you

Comment: Any time. Don't forget to tip your server.

Comment: I have to have 15 reputation for the publicly displayed score to change if I upvote

Comment: That was actually a joke about tipping the server. I got my points. But hang around, SO is fun.